Brown outs with Nordic Instruments PPK2 power profiler
I have a circuit that I know works with 2 AA batteries that are nearly dead (1.4 volts total).
I want to measure the current consumption of the circuit using my Nordic Instruments PPK2 meter. The only way I can get the circuit to function using the PPK2 is if I apply 3 volts or higher to the circuit. It appears as though the circuit may be 'browning out' because when the LoRa radio sends a packet, it seems to reboot.
I can't seem to find any settings on PPK2 software that would limit the current. I also don't observe a voltage drop when the radio pulses but I am just using a standard volt meter as I don't have a scope.
Any ideas why the circuit would work fine on two nearly dead AA batteries but not using the PPK2?
I have the positive battery terminal connected to VOUT and the negative battery terminal connected to GND.

Can you link to a product manual? It's not likely that we could find anything more without it

There are several possibilities, since I'm not sure of your setup:

The PPK2 may have a higher ESR.
The sense resistor may be limiting the available current (particularly if you're pulling more than 1 order of magnitude more current in LoRa mode than otherwise).
The USB port you're driving it from may be inadequate, or may suffer from excessive reaction time to a load pull.

The first thing I'd try is a different USB port, preferably an externally powered hub specified to put out more current than you're expecting by a factor of 3.  If that doesn't work, you could hook up another supply in parallel set to about 2.5V, which can kick in during the load pull, although this would underrepresent your current during the brownout period.
If it's a reaction time issue to changes in the load, rather than an inadequate source, a large electrolytic cap (~1000uF) might help.
